# Java - find a color representing all colors in an image

Tags: java, image, colors, awt, photoshop

I am wanting to sample an image to return a single color that "looks" that a good representation of the colors sampled.  I have tried two methods:

- Taking an average of all the red, greens, and blues and creating an image from that.  This rarely produces a color that looks like it came from the image.
- Finding the "dominant" color from the image.  This entails finding the most common color from the image.  This is better, but for example, the Mona Lisa produces a dark purple color.  This seems to capture the darker areas of the image, but it is ignoring all of the lighter areas in the top corners and on her skin. I would like a color that represents the dark areas and the light areas.

Photoshop has a "average blur" that produces a single color for an image.  For the Mona Lisa, this looks like:
 [image: Mona Lisa through average blur on photoshop]

In this case, each quarter represents the respective quarter of the Mona Lisa.  This is eventually what I am looking for, but let's start with the image as a whole.

I would love to know how photoshop gets these colors.

Thanks!

Comment: ...So what is your question?? Do you want to know how photoshop did it or are you asking how to do it in Java?

Comment: Wild guess: maybe Photoshop is using the same color averaging method you describe in your first bullet point, but they're not using the RGB color space. Maybe they convert to [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) first.

Comment: DreadHeadedDeveloper, I am looking to do it in Java, but I thought the photoshop reference would help.

Comment: Kevin, thank you, I will look into HSV.