# How does photoshop calculate the "average blur" (average color) of an image?

Tags: image, colors, photoshop, blur

This is what photoshop produces for the "average blur" of the Mona Lisa image for each respective quarter.  What is the algorithm for doing so?  I am looking to replicate it in a simple manner.:
 [image: Mona Lisa through average blur on photoshop]

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - find a color representing all colors in an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478533/java-find-a-color-representing-all-colors-in-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to be sure of that unless you can get the source code of Photoshop but the usual way to do this is to :

- add all the r, g, b values of every pixel in the quarter;
- divide the sum of those values by the number of pixel in the quarter;
- create a new color with the resulting r, g, b values.

This new color is the average color of the quarter.

For more information and complete code look [here](http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/extract-average-colours-from-bitmapdata).