# how to achieve effect like photoshop's average blur in android?

Tags: android, photoshop

I want to do a function like photoshop's average blur (Filter>Blue>Average)

but I tried something like  get average color from image in android,
but really buggy. most image turn out to be black or gray or white.

any lib available?  or Is there any app can do this?

the effect just like this.

**[image: GOAL:]**

Comment: What did you use to get the average color?

Comment: I need this function to compare two different image, if they looks alike from distance view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question. And the answer is not a straight forward one.

1. Looking around I've found this article: [How does photoshop calculate the "average blur" (average color) of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498619/how-does-photoshop-calculate-the-average-blur-average-color-of-an-image)
2. Which points to this article, which has code: http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/extract-average-colours-from-bitmapdata
3. This shouldn't be hard to implement on Android.
4. However, I do suggest you do not implement this in Java, which is very slow. Rather do this on [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html), which is a Google technology designed for this type of missions - a cross architecture, highly optimized C code to handle graphic tasks and image manipulation.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, I have already tried something like this , but only white or black with different value returned mostly.

Comment: This suggests a problem with your implementation of the algorithm. Did you first verify it on pure C?

Comment: sorry, I haven't verify it, I'll try it and feedback later. I almost gave up on this app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library to make blur any background or image https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind

Comment: This is blur, but not average color blur.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the color you are getting from the average of the color values, you could try Android's [`Palette`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) class. The class was made to generate a palette of colors based on the prominent colors of an image to create something like this:

[image]

This would have to be done asynchronously from the UI thread:

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
        // Use generated palette
    }
});
```

You can try the different methods available from the `Palette` class (i.e. `getVibrantColor`, `getMutedColor`, `getDarkVibrantColor`, etc.) to see which returns values you like.

Comment: thanks a lot, result seems good, but this doesn't looks accurate.